# cannot convert character into numeric in R

Tags: r, excel, character, numeric, dataformat

I copy and pasted the weather information from the following website "weather underground" for some data analysis and the data looks like below:

https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/KCACHINO13/table/2018-04-10/2018-04-10/daily

[image]

As you can see, the temperature and other information all have the text with it so I cannot conduct any calculation. In the excel, I used substitute(xx,"F","") to remove the F from the "Temperature" column, but then I wanted to convert Farenheit to Celcius using convert(xx,"F","C"), I could not get the outcome. I think there is something wrong with the data itself. I formatted the cell into number or copy and paste the value to a new column, but neither of them worked.

Then I import the data.frame into R and try to do some data formating using R. I checked the class of the Temperature column, which shows "character":

```
class(a$Temperature)
#"character"

a$Temperature <- gsub("F","",a$Temperature)
# this command remmoved "F"

as.numeric(a$Temperature)
#Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion 

as.numeric(unlist(a$Temperature))
#still the same warning message
```

From the excel, I created the new column removing "F" from temperature, and used this in R to convert "character" to "numeric", I still got the warning message. I don't know how to deal with this problem. Could someone help me with this？ Thank you!

As recommended below, I am pasting the output from

```
dput(head(a))

#structure(list(Time = structure(c(-2209075140, -2209074840, -2209074540, 
-2209074240, -2209073940, -2209073640), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Temperature = c("60.0 ", "59.9 ", "59.8 ", "59.7 ", 
"59.6 ", "59.5 "), `T(F)` = c("60.0 ", "59.9 ", "59.8 ", "59.7 ", 
"59.6 ", "59.5 "), `Dew Point` = c("48.2 F", "48.1 F", "48.4 F", 
"48.3 F", "48.2 F", "48.1 F"), Humidity = c("65 %", "65 %", "66 %", 
"66 %", "66 %", "66 %"), Wind = c("WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", 
"WSW", "WSW"), Speed = c("0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", 
"0.0 mph", "0.0 mph"), Gust = c("0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", 
"0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph"), Pressure = c("29.88 in", "29.88 in", 
"29.88 in", "29.88 in", "29.88 in", "29.88 in"), `Precip. Rate.` = c("0.00 in", 
"0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in"), `Precip. Accum.` = c("0.00 in", 
"0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in"), UV = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Solar = c("0 w/m²", "0 w/m²", "0 w/m²", "0 w/m²", 
"0 w/m²", "0 w/m²")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: what is a$Temperature printing as? I am suspecting that it is either the degree symbol or the space between the number

Comment: Could you use `dput(head(your_data_object _here))`, run it and copy the result and paste it in your post?

Comment: `a[-c(1,5)] <- lapply(a[-c(1,5)], function(x) as.numeric(gsub("[^\\.[:digit:]]", "", x)))`.

Comment: @NotThatKindODr  You are right, there is a degree symbol but it is not shown in either excel or my r data.frame "a". I guess that is the problem.

Comment: @ThoVu I pasted the output in the post:)

Comment: @XM_Z Tho did pretty much what I was going to recommend in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert only Temperature column, here is an option you may consider.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c("12:04 AM", "12:09 AM", "12:14 AM", "12:19 AM", 
"12:24 AM", "12:29 AM"), Temperature = c("69.4 F", "69.2 F", 
"68.8 F", "68.5 F", "68.3 F", "68.0 F"), Dew.Point = c("45.9 F", 
"46.0 F", "45.8 F", "45.7 F", "45.7 F", "45.7 F"), Humidity = c("43 %", 
"43 %", "44 %", "44 %", "44 %", "45 %"), Wind = c("NE", "NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE"), Speed = c("0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", 
"0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph"), Gust = c("0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", 
"0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph", "0.0 mph"), Pressure = c("29.93 in", 
"29.94 in", "29.94 in", "29.95 in", "29.95 in", "29.95 in"), 
    Precip..Rate. = c("0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", 
    "0.00 in", "0.00 in"), Precip..Accum. = c("0.00 in", "0.00 in", 
    "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in", "0.00 in"), UV = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Solar = c("0 w/m²", "0 w/m²", "0 w/m²", 
    "0 w/m²", "0 w/m²", "0 w/m²")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Temperature2 = as.numeric(str_extract(Temperature, "[\\d\\.]+"))) %>% 
  relocate(Temperature2, .after = Temperature)

df2[, 2:3]
#   Temperature Temperature2
# 1      69.4 F         69.4
# 2      69.2 F         69.2
# 3      68.8 F         68.8
# 4      68.5 F         68.5
# 5      68.3 F         68.3
# 6      68.0 F         68.0
str(df2$Temperature2)
# num [1:6] 69.4 69.2 68.8 68.5 68.3 68
```

Comment: relocate is a neat function, I didn't know it existed, thanks for sharing

Comment: Thank you! May I ask about the relocate function? I got the R message: 
Error in relocate(., Temperature2, .after = Temperature) : 
  could not find function "relocate"
It seems "relocate" is either a basic function in R from online, but I couldn't find it in my R...

Comment: It is available for dplyr > 1.0.0 version. If you update to the newest one, then here you go. You can feel free to remove it if you don't like. Here I just make it easier for you to see the result.

Comment: It worked out! I applied this code to my data.frame and it works for all the columns. Thank you! I just have one more question: I tried to look up [\\d\\.]+, but I don't quite understand. \d means any digit, \. means period, and + means one or more repetitions. What does the first \ mean, and what does this whole code together mean?

Comment: @XM_Z : \\d is to match digits, while \\. is to match the dot.

Comment: Because d and . are the special characters, we need to escape it by using \\ in R. The code means we will match all digits and the dot. We don't get anything else. Then we can convert to numeric numbers.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation! That helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, helps.
In this function there is nested few different functions, such as changing from character variable to numeric. Also gsub, which changes comma to empty space. You should just change comma to letter what you are changing. Never tried if it works with letters, but this might be one solution. Here is the code:

data666 <- apply(data, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",", "", x))))

Apply function apllies functions in for whole dataset. 2 means that it does it column by column. If you want to chaange it row by ro you have to change 2 to 1.